# Вывести переменную парсера через бота Discord на Python

Tags: python, бот, discord

**Пытаюсь вывести переменную items через команду бота, но она не определяется. Как решить?**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot


Bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix= '!')
client = discord.Client()

URL = 'site'
HEADERS = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.198 Safari/537.36', 'accept': '*/*'}

def get_html(url, params=None):
    r = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS, params=params)
    return r

def get_content(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.find_all('div', class_='player-name')

    print(items)



def parse():
    html = get_html(URL)
    if html.status_code == 200:
        get_content(html.text)


parse()

@Bot.command(pass_context = True)
async def code(ctx):
    html = get_html(URL)
    await ctx.send(html)

Bot.run('--------------')
```

Comment: А почему из `get_content` не возвращаете `items`?

Comment: Возвратил:
~~~
def get_content(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.find_all('div', class_='player-name')
    return items



def parse():
    html = get_html(URL)
    if html.status_code == 200:
        get_content(html.text)


parse()

@Bot.command(pass_context = True)
async def code(ctx):
    html = get_html(URL)
    await ctx.send(get_content(items))
~~~
Но результата не принесло, та же ошибка:
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: NameError: name 'items' is not defined

Comment: Для `parse` аналогично, раз она вызывает `get_content`, то ей или его обработать, или вернуть, чтобы там где `parse` будет вызвана получить результат. И вы явно не весь код привели, т.к. в текущем явно не будет ошибки с `items`. Вообще, `items` существует только внутри функции, поэтому ее нужно вернуть из функции, чтобы ее значение стало доступно извне

Comment: Ещё не понял как тут форматирование кода в комментарии сделать, кину скриншотом.

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/719968531420020743/782331337574973440/unknown.png

Формально items я вернул в get_content, но вызвать его не получается.

Comment: Под вопросом есть кнопка `править` ею и добавляйте код в вопрос. Форматировать код можно через `{}` на панели в редакторе или добавляя \`\`\` до и после кода. Почему у вас в строке с ошибкой в скрине передается в функцию get_content не html, а items?

Comment: Если передавать html, то пытается вывести всю страницу, соответственно ловя ошибку 
{TypeError: object of type 'Response' has no len()}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подправил код из вопроса и теперь `items` будет передано в `ctx.send`. Места, где изменил, выделил

Но есть вопрос: понимает ли `ctx.send` значение из `items`? А это результат выполнения `soup.find_all`, что, является списком элементов `Tag` из `bs4`. Возможно, нужно будет обработать `items`, чтобы, например, получить строку.

Код:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot


Bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix= '!')
client = discord.Client()

URL = 'site'
HEADERS = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.198 Safari/537.36', 'accept': '*/*'}

def get_html(url, params=None):
    r = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS, params=params)
    return r

def get_content(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.find_all('div', class_='player-name')
    return items
    # ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

def parse():
    r = get_html(URL)
    r.raise_for_status()
    return get_content(r.content)
    # ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


@Bot.command(pass_context = True)
async def code(ctx):
    items = parse()
    await ctx.send(items)
    # ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Bot.run('--------------')
```

Comment: Всё заработало как нужно, буду разбираться как и где накосячил)
Спасибо.

Comment: @Sterof, пожалуйста :)